# HCE on Nexus 7 (2013) with PN532 communication

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, apdu, hce

I am communicating between PN532 on Arduino Uno with Nexus 7 running Kitkat 4.4.2, 
The HCE program I had from here: 
https://github.com/grundid/host-card-emulation-sample 
I run the sample program on Nexus 7, and on Arduino I try to send APDU command:

```
uint8_t PN532::APDU ()
{
uint8_t message[] = {
0x00, /* CLA */
0xA4, /* INS */
0x04, /* P1  */
0x00, /* P2  */
0x07, /* Lc  */
0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
0x00  /* Le  */ };

/* Prepare the first command */

/* Send the command */
if (HAL(writeCommand)(message, 13)) {
    Serial.println(F("Go here 1"));
    return 0;
}
Serial.println(F("Go here 2"));
/* Read the response packet */
return (0 < HAL(readResponse)(message, sizeof(message)));}
```

Here is my APDU service file: apduservice.html

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/servicedesc"
android:requireDeviceUnlock="false" >

<aid-group
    android:category="other"
    android:description="@string/aiddescription" >
    <aid-filter android:name="F0010203040506" />
</aid-group>
```

but I cannot get any response from the Nexus 7, and from Nexus 7 I also didn't record any signals? Does anyone know what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: What library are you using on the Arduino side? What are writeCommand and readResponse doing? How did the PN532 activate the HCE phone prior to sending these commands?

Comment: This is the library I get from:    
    `<https://github.com/don/Ndef>  and 
    <https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532>`  
writeCommand is to push message buffer to other device, and readResponse is to receive the response. 
To activate the HCE phone, if I try to push A4 1 0 then the phone response with random UID, but when I run the Hcedemo program, it didn't response, so I stop push A4 1 0 anymore, and push message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Seeed-Studio PN532 library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532), you shouldn't need to create your own commands within the library (ie. what you did with `uint8_t PN532::APDU () {...}`.

Instead, you can use the methods that are already there. To establish a connection with a tag/contactless smartcard (or rather to enumerate the available tags/cards), you would start with `inListPassiveTarget()`. If the tag/smartcard supports APDUs, it will later automatically be activated for APDU-based communcation. Then you can use `inDataExchange()` to send and receive APDUs.

So, if you included the PN532 library like this:

```
PN532_xxx pn532hal(...);
PN532 nfc(pn532hal);
```

You could then use the library like this:

```
bool success = nfc.inListPassiveTarget();
if (success) {
    uint8_t apdu = {
        0x00, /* CLA */
        0xA4, /* INS */
        0x04, /* P1  */
        0x00, /* P2  */
        0x07, /* Lc  */
        0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06,
        0x00  /* Le  */
    };
    uint8_t response[255];
    uint8_t responseLength = 255;
    success = nfc.inDataExchange(apdu, sizeof(apdu), response, &responseLength);
    if (success) {
        // response should now contain the R-APDU you received in response to the above C-APDU (responseLength data bytes)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working :) 
Can I ask one more question: What is the APDU for the next message after this?
And from now on, the command between HCE and PN532 (to write/read data) will be based on APDU - ISO 7816-4, right?

Comment: That depends on how **you** design **your** protocol. This could be any APDU as long as it compies to ISO 7816-4.